TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString') in reactjs filter
I am working in a react project an d here i have one endpoint for products, i want to filter products by name

function Productos(){  
    const {loading,productos,setProductos}=useFetchProducts()
    const [buscar, setBuscar] = useState("");

    const handleChange = e =>{
        setBuscar(e.target.value)
        filtrar(e.target.value);
    }

    const filtrar = (inputBusqueda) =>{
        var resultado = productos.filter((element) =>{
            if(element.name.toString().toLowerCase().includes(inputBusqueda.toLowerCase()))
            {
                return element
            }
        });
    setProductos(resultado)
    }

        return (
                <>
                    <Loading loading={loading}>
                    <div style={style.buscar}>
                    <input type="text" value={buscar} onChange={handleChange} />
                    <Button variant="primary" type="submit" style={style.button}>Buscar</Button>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div>
                        <Tabla/>
                    </div>
                    </Loading>
                </>
            );
        }



export default Productos;


endpoint not working showing error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString')
If you know how to fix it let me know

The error is very helpful. It says you're trying to read the property toString of an undefined object. So, look at your code. Where do you see toString?

element.name.toString() this is the only place in your code sample that i see toString so this should be where you are getting the error so double check the value received in productos and see if any of them are missing the name property.
If so and if you can not correct the data, then check for element.name to be defined before evaluating.
